# Seaborn automatic color selection

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I'm using seaborn to create a horizontal bar chart. From [this](http://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/horizontal_barplot.html) example, here is how I am setting colors.

```
sns.set_color_codes("pastel")
sns.barplot(x="total", y="abbrev", data=crashes, label="Total", color="b")
```

So in this example the field 'total' will have the color "b" (for blue) from the "pastel" palette.

I have around 60 different fields, and I do not want to set all the colors manually. Is there a way to let seaborn choose the colors (and even the palette) automatically?

As it stands my plan is to create the barplots in a cycle

```
for field in fields:
    sns.set_color_codes(foo)
    sns.barplot(x=field, y="abbrev", data=crashes, label=field, color="bar")
```

where `foo` and `bar` are somehow generated for me by seaborn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the argument `palette=` in the barplot method as specified in documentation [Seaborn Barplot](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html).

A really good example of values that you can provide to `palette` method is available at [Seaborn Color Palette](http://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/color_palettes.html)

```
my_palette = sns.color_palette("muted")
sns.barplot(x=field, y="abbrev", data=crashes, label=field, palette=my_palette)
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked well together with `my_palette = sns.color_palette("Set1", n_colors=len(fields), desat=.5)` and then setting `palette="Set1"`.

Comment: Great. FYI, Different color palette's can also be combined to create another one i.e you can use some colors from **Set1** and **Set2** to create your own.